# Ruby on Rails: remove element from array by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there some sort of short hand for

```
  @notifications = Notification.find(:all, :conditions => ['expires_at > ?', Time.now])

  notif = Notification.find(:all, cookie[0].to_i)
  @notifications.delete(notif[0]) if not notif.empty?
```

cookie is an id of a notification stored into cookies.
this is in an iteration, that removes notifications that the user doesn't want to see.

thanks! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is an array of activerecord objects, you could delete from the database like this.

`Notification.delete_all(:id => cookie[0].to_i)`

If this is just an array, then you can use the delete if

`@notifications.delete_if{|x| x == cookie[0].to_i}`

Comment: an array has no method, delete_all. =\

Comment: is this an array of activerecord objects?  and if so, so you want to delete just from the array or delete from the database?  I added a one-liner to delete from an array.  Not totally sure what @notifications is now.

Comment: close,       @notifications.delete_if{|x| x.id == cookie[0].to_i}
  did the trick. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Now you could just use the `delete_at( index )` method:

```
array = ['item0', 'item1', 2, 3]
array.delete_at 1
# => "item1" 
array.delete_at 2
# => 3
array
# => ["item0", 3]
```

You could do the same with `slice!( index )`.

Note: `delete_at` is a mutator method even if it doesn't end in `!`, so don't rely on its return value, it will only be the deleted item.

Reference:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at